# Spark Streaming and static join issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a two python files

```
File1.py:

def func1(param1,streamingdf):
 global staticdf
 ##static dataframe 
 Staticdf=spark.read.format(‘delta’).load()
  streamingdf.writestream.foreachbatch(func2(batchdf,batchid))

staticdf.join(streamingdf) ## it is not working as staticdf is defined as global


## Python file 2

def func2(batchdf,batchid):
 Batchdf.filter logic
 staticdf.union(batchdf)
 return staticdf
```

But here the global dataframe is returning correct data but when I tried to join with streaming dataframe , the output is returning empty but when I unpersist manually onetime stream is working.could anyone help me on this?